# Android Room: как узнать, что миграция произошла?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Я перевожу старый проект на Android Jetpack, в том числе мигрирую старую БД на Room. Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: в старой схеме хранения данных часть информации находилась в БД, а другая часть в файловой системе в папке `Android/data`. Было решено перенести эту часть в новую схему Room, используя механизм `Migration` и скопировать данные из файлов в БД. Но встаёт проблема - я не могу получить `Context` из `Migration`, необходимый для доступа к `data` каталогу с помощью `getExternalFilesDir`, а также я не могу узнать что `Migration` завершён и что миграция вообще была, поскольку нет `onUpgrade` callback. Room позволяет установить callback в трёх случаях - `onOpen`, `onCreate` и `onDestructiveMigration`, но ни один случае не подходит. `onCreate` вызывается только при первом создании БД и не вызывается после миграции на новую схему. Каков правильный путь в данном случае? Как я могу узнать, что миграция произошла и выполнить дополнительные действия?

Comment: Мне лично непонятно зачем миграции объявляют константами (да и не выяснял), но билдер принимает объект, наследник класса `Migrarion` и думаю что ничего не помешает создать его на месте перед добавлением в билдер и передать туда контекст либо собственный коллбек, который оттуда вызвать.

Comment: @woesss звучит разумно, спасибо.